# WebApplication referencing assembly with dynamic assemblyName

Tags: c#, asp.net

We are using customize MSBuild to set our assesmblies names to Assembly_Configuration_Platform format:

```
<AssemblyName>Assembly_$(Configuration)_$(Platform)</AssemblyName>
```

such as:

```
Customers_Debug_x86.dll
```

This works and builds fine with project references when used in the context of an application. However, in an ASP WebApplication we get a "FileNotFoundException", And it seems the system is looking for the non-customized assembbly name:

> Could not load file or assembly '.dll,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Any Ideas?

Thnaks,

Leah